# SpringFox context path duplicated when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9, springfox

I have a Spring Boot resource server using SpringFox to generate Swagger UI documentation for the REST API. I'm using Spring version 2.2.4.RELEASE and SpringFox version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

When I run the application self hosted the URLs in the documentation are correct, they look like this:

http://localhost:8080/customers

But when I run the same application on tomcat the URLs look like this:

https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/my-app-1.0.0/my-app-1.0.0/customers

The application path is duplicated for all the APIs, the path should be:

https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/my-app-1.0.0/customers

Another issue is the api-docs link, this is wrong for the self hosted but correct for tomcat hosted environments. Both hosting environments including the application  which is wrong when self hosted but then its not duplicated like all the others in tomcat:

http://localhost:8080/my-app-1.0.0/v2/api-docs

Also, the documentation is including the application path in the documentation (not duplicated here). The application path is not included when running self hosted.

I tried specifying the context path in the application.yml file but this had no effect (I tried both server.servlet.contextPath and server.servlet.context-path)

**How can I get SpringFox to generate the correct URLs?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swagger is adding context root twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778286/swagger-is-adding-context-root-twice)